# Allure2 and Selenide - @Step annotation not displayed in report

Tags: annotations, report, allure, selenide

I would like to add @Step annotation to my tests to make test results more readable.

@DisplayName is working as expected but @Step not

I'm running tests using command:
**mvn clean test**

and than generating results using:
**allure serve /pathToResults/allure-results**

here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>allure.selenide</groupId>
<artifactId>allure.selenide</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

sample file with tests:

```
package allure.selenide;

import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide;
import com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger;
import io.qameta.allure.Description;
import io.qameta.allure.Step;
import io.qameta.allure.junit4.DisplayName;
import io.qameta.allure.selenide.AllureSelenide;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

@DisplayName("My Tests")
public class ExampleTest {

@Before
public void setUp(){
    SelenideLogger.addListener("AllureSelenide", new AllureSelenide().screenshots(true).savePageSource(true));
}

@Test
@DisplayName("My Test Name")
@Description("Some detailed test description")
public void SampleTest(){
    openPage();
}

@Step("Open page Step...")
private void openPage(){
    Selenide.open("https://www.google.com");
}
}
```

Any idea how to display step names in generated report ?

generater report: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add aspectjweaver dependency, correct pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>allure.selenide</groupId>
<artifactId>allure.selenide</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.2</aspectj.version>
</properties>
    
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
</argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```